# YouTube API site URL token limits?

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing an application using the YouTube API that allows users to browse their account (Uploads, favorites etc.) from an external site. The current site is setup as a WordPress multi-site network (which is only important here for the URL structure).

Each site is installed into a sub-directory, so for example the main site would be
http://www.mainsite.com

and each site URL structure would be:

- http://www.mainsite.com/site-1/
- http://www.mainsite.com/site-2/

I've setup a channel for each of the sites in the network so each site can view separate videos.

For each site I've installed I've setup a separate Google Project and am using a unique API key. I can authenticate on one site and store the refresh token in the database for later use.

That all works, but when I go to authenticate on a second site, the first site's refresh/access tokens get revoked and the second site works while the first does not. 
I receive a response from the API on the first site "Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'". I can then revoke the tokens, and re-authenticate and things work again until i try and authenticate on a different iste.

How come I can only have one site authenticated at a time if they are each using separate api keys and access tokens to hit the API? Is it because all of the JavaScript origins originate from the same URL?

If so, is there a work around where I can have all of the sites in the network connected without having to re-authenticate each time I want to view the channel? Is there some sort of limitation here that I'm overlooking?

It seems like only one site in the network can be communicating with the API at a time even tho the access tokens and api keys are unique to each site.

Comment: what does your authentication (POST) request look like? Also, this most likely cuz your token is expired or you have hit your token refresh limits.

Answer (score 0):

Use an api key:
client->setDeveloperKey('key goes here');

You can get the key from your api console, set it as a server key.